# how to solve json decode returns null error

Tags: php, json

My API URL Returned code in browser as shown below.
 but  `json_decode($api_url,true);` returns null. 
i checked `json_last_error();`, it returns 4(json error syntax).
it worked with `json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url),true);`
why it isn't work with json_decode. please help

```
{"dataset":{"id":27153572,"dataset_code":"20MICRONS_A_DEBT","database_code":"DEB","name":"20 Microns Limited,Total Debt","description":"\u003cp\u003e20 Microns Limited(NSE:20MICRONS)-Total Debt(Annual)\u003c/p\u003e","refreshed_at":"2018-09-21T08:04:08.278Z","newest_available_date":"2018-03-31","oldest_available_date":"2005-03-31","column_names":["PERIOD","STANDALONE","CONSOLIDATED"],"frequency":"annual","type":"Time Series","premium":true,"limit":null,"transform":null,"column_index":null,"start_date":"2005-03-31","end_date":"2018-03-31","data":[["2018-03-31",128.56,133.68],["2017-03-31",144.9,151.73],["2016-03-31",155.18,163.41],["2015-03-31",152.8,164.62],["2014-03-31",162.01,176.64],["2013-03-31",148.49,164.73],["2012-03-31",144.67,158.6],["2011-03-31",81.42,120.31],["2010-03-31",84.35,87.35],["2009-03-31",58.62,58.62],["2008-03-31",46.52,null],["2007-03-31",42.46,null],["2006-03-31",40.03,null],["2005-03-31",38.98,null]],"collapse":null,"order":null,"database_id":14992}}
```

Comment: Because `$api_url` is a url and not a json data. __Understand the difference__?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do has no sense. `$api_url` is just an url so when you try to decode it then it doesn't have a `json` stucture and it will throw an exeption.

What you should decode is the data that this url returns to you.

So First you should get data from url then use `json_decode($api_url,true);`.

To get data you can use `file_get_contents` or `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

Props to u_mulder who hit the nail on the head but I want to break this down for you a little.

Purpose of file_get_contents():
The file_get_contents() function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to read the contents of a file into a string.

Please note that the 'file' can be a file residing on your web server or a remote file (URL), which in essence will give you a web document back.

Purpose of json_decode():
The json_decode() function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to decode a JSON string. It converts a JSON encoded string into a PHP variable.

With that in mind you can see that performing json_decode on an invalid JSON string or a URL will render your result as NULL.

```
json_decode('https://www.website.com')
```

This is essentially what you are doing. performing the file_get_contents inside your json_decode first converts your URL/File ('https://www.website.com') into a string, that string then having JSON is then converted into an array by json_decode.